# Print Powershell Regex captures to an output file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file, `input.txt`, containing text like this:

```
GRP123456789
    123456789012
GRP234567890
    234567890123
GRP456789012
    "A lot of text. More text. Blah blah blah: Foobar." (Source Error) (Blah blah blah)
GRP567890123
    Source Error
GRP678901234
    Source Error
GRP789012345
    345678901234
    456789012345
```

I'm attempting to capture all occurrences of "GRP#########" on the condition that at least one number is on the next line.

So GRP123456789 is valid, but GRP456789012 and GRP678901234 are not.

The RegEx pattern I came up with on http://regexstorm.net/tester is: `(GRP[0-9]{9})\s\n\s+[0-9]`

The PowerShell script I have so far, based off this site http://techtalk.gfi.com/windows-powershell-extracting-strings-using-regular-expressions/, is:

```
$input_path = 'C:\Users\rtaite\Desktop\input.txt'
$output_file = 'C:\Users\rtaite\Desktop\output.txt'

$regex = '(GRP[0-9]{9})\s\n\s+[0-9]'

select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Values } > $output_file
```

I'm not getting any output, and I'm not sure why.

Any help with this would be appreciated as I'm just trying to understand this better.

Comment: Try `(?m)^GRP[0-9]{9}(?=\r?\n\s+[0-9])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Nope, still no output.

Comment: Try the above one with a correction of `$_.Values` to `$_.Value`. Also, try replacing `$_.Values` with `$_.Groups[1].Value` and try with your own regex (it should work if your file has CRLF endings).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately no, still no output. Would Value only give me one result, instead of multiple with Values? Or is Values simply invalid? I tried with and without Groups and both forms of Value, and for hell of it tried setting the Group index to 0. Nothing.

Comment: There is no `Values` property, only `Value`. You will get all occurrences because you ask to fetch `-AllMatches`.

Comment: Interesting, a snippet of code worked using Values with a different example taken from the site I listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the text input into a single string before passing it to `Select-String`, otherwise the cmdlet will operate on each line individually and thus never find a match.

```
Get-Content $input_path | Out-String |
    Select-String $regex -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value } |
    Set-Content $output_file
```

If you're using PowerShell v3 or newer you can replace `Get-Content | Out-String` with `Get-Content -Raw`.

Comment: Both methods you mentioned worked with my original pattern, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To strip strings from a text file using a pattern, then the best tool for the job is the `Select-String`. This is also has a parameter called `-Context` which lets you capture lines before or after the matched line, ideal for just this problem.

So my solution would be something like this:

```
Select-String 'input.txt' -Pattern '^GRP[0-9]{9}' -Context 0, 1 | ? {
    $_.Context.PostContext -match '\d'
} | Select -ExpandProperty line | Set-Content 'output_file.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
[regex]::Matches($(Get-Content '.\Desktop\new 1.txt'), "GRP\d+(?=\s+\d)") |
    % { $_.value | Out-File .\Desktop\new-1-matches.txt -Append }
```

I achieved the following output from your sample file:

```
GRP123456789
GRP234567890
GRP789012345
```

Comment: You may want to put the `Out-File` after the `ForEach-Object` to avoid repeatedly appending to the output file.